# Asp.net core routing ambiguousActionException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 `controllers` and I'm receiving the error:

```
> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
> actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
> WebApi.Controllers.BlacklistController.GetBlacklists (WebApi)
> WebApi.Controllers.WhitelistController.GetWhitelists (WebApi)
```

Here are my controllers

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/infrastructure/blacklist")]
    public sealed class BlacklistController : Controller
    {
         private readonly IInfrastructure _infrastructure;
         public BlacklistController(IInfrastructure infrastucture) => _infrastructure = infrastucture;

         [HttpGet]
         [Route("/")]
         public async Task<IEnumerable<BlacklistedAgent>> GetBlacklists() => await _infrastructure.GetBlacklistedAgents().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


WhitelistController.cs:

    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/infrastructure/whitelist")]
    public sealed class WhitelistController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IInfrastructure _infrastructure;
        public WhitelistController(IInfrastructure infrastructure) => _infrastructure = infrastructure;

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WhitelistRequest>> GetWhitelists() => await _infrastructure.GetPendingWhitelistRequests().ConfigureAwait(false);

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<WhiteListingResponse>> RequestWhitelisting(Guid agentId, string fqdn)
        {
            var result = await _infrastructure.RequestWhitelistingForAgent(agentId, fqdn).ConfigureAwait(false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case WhiteListingResponse.Blacklisted:
                    return Forbid();
                case WhiteListingResponse.SuccessfullyAddedToAwaitingWhitelist:
                    return Ok();
                case WhiteListingResponse.ConflictStopsAddingToAwaitingWhitelist:
                {
                    await _infrastructure.CreateUnresolvedIdentity(agentId, fqdn).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return Conflict();
                }
                default:
                   return BadRequest();
            }
        }
   }
```

Why isn't it `disambiguating` the method based on the `Route attribute` on the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route templates applied to an action that begin with a / don't get combined with route templates applied to the controller.

```
[Route("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]      // Combines to define the route template "Home"
    [Route("Index")] // Combines to define the route template "Home/Index"
    [Route("/")]     // Doesn't combine, defines the route template ""
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Home index";
        var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
        ViewData["Message"] = "Home index" + "var url = Url.Action; =  " + url;
        return View();
    }

    [Route("About")] // Combines to define the route template "Home/About"
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }   
}
```

This is by design and it is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing).